# Android UI widget appear on emulator differently than in emulator

Tags: android, user-interface, widget, emulation

I am building new Android app and i have question on the differences between how UI widgets looks in the emulator and how they look in my device (Samsung S2, OS 4.0.3).

When i run the app in the emulator buttons (BTW, and other UI widget) looks much more "elegant".. buttons (in number picker) are small arrow in blue/gray but in the device buttons (in number picker) are more "regular" (gray rectangle) 
(sorry but I can not load pictures..)

my question is, how can i make the UI widget on my device looks like in the emulator?

Thanks,
Dudy.

Comment: Upload screenshots on imgur for example and provide us a link. I would have tought you are speaking of the Holo theme, but your device runs on ICS.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the other way around - the emulator shows the default skin from Google, while your device shows what the manufacturer has customized (and burned into the operating system of your device).

So you may look into getting "Samsung skins" (if they exist) to make the emulator more close to the real device.

Comment: AFAIK there are no "Samsung skins"for Android Emulators and btw he wants to make the widgets on his device look like pure Android. So the other way around :)

Comment: +Ahmad I got that he wants it the other way around. And there are 3 ways: rooting, complaining until Samsung listens or buying a device that is using the 'Google skin'.

Comment: And of course he can request the Holo theme - and in theory Google requires since 4.1(?) that every device has it, but it may not be present on his device.

Comment: Holo is since 3.0, but I think big OEMs like Samsung even customized that too(if I'm not wrong)

Comment: Holo is since 3.0, but there is no requirement to use it. This requirement is only since 4.1 (iirc). So a 4.0 device is not required to provide Holo to the user.

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry, did not know that :) +1

Answer (score 1):

The nice UI you are talking about is probably the Holo Theme, which was introduced in Android HC, but some OEMs use customized Android Frameworks like Samsung(TouchWiz) or HTC(HTC Sense). If you want to use the same Theme throughout the big range of Android devices you can use third party libraries . A popular Theme, which brings pure Holo to older devices (2.3=<) is [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere). If you use this Theme in your App you'll have the Holo Theme in most Android versions and on most devices.

Comment: You can eather download the lib as a zip or you can clone it with git.